# Unable to run PowerShell Write-EventLog within a DOCKERFILE

Tags: docker, powershell, dockerfile, event-log

In my DOCKERFILE I'm running some PowerShell script which creates a custom event log (on Windows Server), then writes an entry. [I should add that I'm currently doing this only for debug purposes.]

The script/command which creates the event log appear to execute without any problems, but an exception is thrown when writing to the log using...

```
RUN powershell.exe -command Write-EventLog -LogName "my_log_name" -Source "my_source" -Message "EventLog created by DOCKERFILE." -Category 0 -EventID 0 -EntryType Information
```

The following exception is thrown...

```
Write-EventLog : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 
'created'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Write-EventLog -LogName my_log_name -Source my_source -EntryType Messag ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Write-EventLog], Parameter 
   BindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell 
   .Commands.WriteEventLogCommand
```

I also tried wrapping `"EventLog created by DOCKERFILE."` in parentheses but then it complained about the word `by`.

Why does it seem unable to parse `"EventLog created by DOCKERFILE."` as a string argument, but is instead parsing the words within the string?

---

**UPDATE**
Even if I wrap the command in double-quotes and the individual strings in single quotes, I get the same error.

[image]

---

**UPDATE 2**
Removing the quotes and escaping the spaces doesn't work either.

[image]

Comment: Try using single-quotes instead of doubles `'EventLog created by DOCKERFILE'`

Comment: This results in exactly the same exception; `A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'created'.`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ` to escape the spaces:

```
RUN powershell.exe -command Write-EventLog -LogName my_log_name -Source my_source -Message EventLog` created` by` DOCKERFILE. -Category 0 -EventID 0 -EntryType Information
```

See: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#escape

Comment: Thanks @Toni but this still produces the same error. I've added a screenshot of this to the OP.

Comment: I'll updated the sample - please verify

Comment: Still no success. (See `UPDATE 2`.)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me from cmd (except for the unknown source).  I'm not sure if docker has issues with single quotes.  Double quotes are special in cmd.  Note that new-winevent has replaced write-eventlog.

```
powershell write-eventLog my_log_name my_source 0 information 'EventLog created by DOCKERFILE.' -category 0
```

Comment: I also have no problem creating the entry from the command line. It seems to be Docker which is trying too keenly to parse the entire line.

Comment: @awj You could always use underscores in the message and not have quotes at all.